# Removing '#' from URL using htaccess in HTML web page

Tags: html, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to remove the # in the following URL: (www.example.com/#section1). How could I do this using the htaccess file. I am sure this could be done using regular expression, but I am not sure how I would do this.

This is what I have written within the htaccess file `RewriteRule ^[#]`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried? If yes, what? If no, why not?

Comment: Hello. I have tried to use the rewrite engine, but I have been unsuccessful. Have you any ideas on how to solve this problem.

Comment: That's not how it works. You post what you have tried and explain where you are stuck, and we help you out. This involves that you post code that shows your efforts in solving your task on your own.

Comment: I have little experience dealing with regular expression, and would appreciate if you could kindly help without being patronising.

Comment: I am not patronising, I am just telling you what the rules are. You can read the official FAQ on this topic, if you want. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your current logic *"I don't know how to do it, therefore someone else should do it for me."* is flawed.

Comment: I appreciate that, but I have tried to solve the problem myself and am still having difficulty to.

Comment: And I believe you. Just show what you did so far, so that I can tell what you've tried. See my comment #1. We could have been past this point four hours ago.

Comment: And in 4 hours of time (most probably more), even with zero preexisting regex knowledge you could have read enough tutorials (or gone through enough rounds of trial-and-error on sites like https://regex101.com/) to come up with a something that at the very least *almost* works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashes (`#`) are not send to the server, so you can't manipulate them on the server.

If you really need to remove them, you would have to use JavaScript on each page.

```javascript
// Wait for the page to load, and call 'removeHash'.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", removeHash);
document.addEventListener("Load", removeHash);

function removeHash() {
    // If there is no hash, don't do anything.
    if (!location.hash) return;

    // http://<domain></pathname>?<search><#hash>

    // Build an URL for the page, sans the domain and hash
    var url = location.pathname;
    if (location.search) {
        // Include the query string, if any
        url += '?' + location.search;
    }

    // Replace the loaded url with the built url, without reloading the page.
    history.replaceState('', document.title, url);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Markus! The code successfully removed the # from the URL. However, could you explain what you have written because I do not understand all of it. I really appreciate your help :)