# How to remove anchor ("#") from URL with htacces?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is there any way to remove `#` from a URL?

I know how to remove query strings using this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^?]*)\?
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

But is there also any way to remove `#` from the URL? (`Example.com/#removethis`)

Comment: Do these help answer your question? [Removing '#' from URL using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41454241/924299), [URL rewriting removing hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991626/url-rewriting-removing-hash), and [How do you remove anchor tags from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198731/how-do-you-remove-anchor-tags-from-url)

Answer (score 2):

No.

The fragment portion of an HTTP URL is handled entirely client-side. It is never sent to the server. Since the server can't know about it, it can't do anything about it.